# Onclick event inside a for loop passes data of last element for every row

Tags: reactjs, foreach, onclick, href

I am trying to create hyperlinks and on click it should pass the data to the javascript function. I get the data of the last element every time when any of the hyperlinks that are generated is clicked.

```
for(var transaction in transactionList ){

      transactionHistoryMap.push(
        <div>
          <a style={{'cursor':'pointer'}} onClick={() => {this.transactionDetail(key,transactionList[transaction].transactionId,transactionList[transaction].transactionName)}} className='transactionHistoryLinks'>{transactionList[transaction].transactionName}</a><br/>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: do you want to pass the data of only the last element of array `transactionList` in every iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of `closure`. The easiest way to solve this is by using `let` or `const`inside your `loop`. `for(const transaction in transactionList) { ... }`.

Check the example of this problem from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in section **Creating closures in loops: A common mistake**

Answer (score 1):

I have solved using below code, it may help others.

```
 {
      transactionHistory[keyName].map(function(value){
        transactionHistoryMap.push(
          <div>
            <a style={{'cursor':'pointer'}} onClick={() => {this.transactionDetail(keyName,value.transactionId,value.transactionName)}}  className='transactionHistoryLinks'>{value.transactionName}</a><br/>
          </div>
        )
      },this
      )}
```